# Indicator overlay on graph

Tags: python, plotly, widget, slider, plotly-python

[image]

I create graph that recalculates with my values in Slider. I am interested in show metric (that mean area on curve or total debit). For this I use `indicator` from plotly. Unfortunately, I cannot plot my line and metric (indicator) in separate figures.

I use:

1. Hbox(FigureWidget(fig1.data,fig2.data), but notebook didn't show my graph (Just empty cell)
2. I try use make_subplots, but can't understand how combine this with FigureWidget

Please, read my code, and advice ideas for solve this problem

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import widgets
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
#
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'iframe'
#
# desc = widgets.VBox([widgets.HTML(value="<b>PRR</b>"),widgets.HTML(value="<b>CR</b>")]
#

prr_slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=Product_Return_Rate*100,
    min=1.0,
    max=100.0,
    step=1.0,
    description='Product return rate',
    continuous_update=False,
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}
)
cr_slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=Connect_Rate*100,
    min=1.0,
    max=100.0,
    step=1.0,
    description='Collection rate',
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}
)
ui = widgets.VBox(children=[prr_slider, cr_slider])

debit_summary = model['own_debit'].sum()

data_line = go.Scatter(x=model.index,
           y=model['own_debit'], 
            mode='lines',
            name='Debit in fact')
goal = go.Scatter(x=model.index,
           y=model['goal_debit'], 
            mode='lines',
            name='Goal debit')

metric = go.Indicator(value=debit_summary, 
            mode='number',
            number = {'prefix': "$"},
            domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 3})

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
# subplots = make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,layout=go.Layout(
#                         title=dict(
#                             text='The forecasting a debit in payday'
#                         )
# ),
#                          data=[data_line,goal]
                         
# )
# fig = go.FigureWidget(subplots)
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=[data_line,goal,metric],
                    layout=go.Layout(
                        title=dict(
                            text='The forecasting a debit in payday'
                        )
                    ))

fig.update_yaxes(tickformat=",.1f",
                 automargin=True,
                 ticksuffix="$")

def response(PRR,CR):
    '''
    Product_Return_Rate - PRR
    Connect_Rate - CRR 
    '''
    Product_Return_Rate = PRR/100
    Connect_Rate = CR/100
    global model
    model = forecast(model,Product_Return_Rate,Connect_Rate)
    debit_summary = model['own_debit'].sum()
    #
    in_fact,goal,metric  = fig.data
    in_fact.update(go.Scatter(x=model.index,
           y=model['own_debit'], 
            mode='lines',
            name='Debit in fact')
                  )
    metric.update(value=debit_summary)
    goal.update(go.Scatter(x=model.index,
           y=model['goal_debit'], 
            mode='lines',
            name='Goal debit')
               )
    fig.show()

out = widgets.interactive_output(response, {'PRR': prr_slider, 'CR': cr_slider})
display(ui, out)
```

#https://plotly.com/python/indicator/

Thank you